# geometry (similarity transformation about ellipses)

Tags: geometry

Consider the ellipses $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and $\frac{x^2}{a_1^2}+\frac{y^2}{b_1^2}=1$. Find a necessary and sufficient condition for the ellipses to be similar. (The relation should relate $a$, $b$, $a_1$ and $b_1$)

Definition of similar:
let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two ellipses, if there exists a dialation $H_v,r$ such that
$H_v,r(E_1)=E_2$, then they are similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the two ellipses have the same center and the same orientation, don't you think that $$\frac{a_1}{a}=\frac{b_1}{b}$$ is sufficient ?